# How to prevent javascript library load for IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How to prevent the load of the D3 library for IE8 (and below) ?

```
<head>
    <script src="../lib/d3/d3.v2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: useful [link](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) about targeting IE browsers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<head>
    <!--[if !IE || gte IE 9]><!-->
        <script src="../lib/d3/d3.v2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: this would not work anymore for IE10 and greter.. forget about browser sniffing... it's evil (IMHO)

Comment: It will. It will just act as nonIE browser.

Comment: Thx; simply change the condition as following :  <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <script src="../lib/d3/d3.v2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- <![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
<script src="../lib/d3/d3.v2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Why? the if condition comment is only for IE.

Comment: This will load the library if the browser is IE6 or 7, which is not what Marc Polizzi wants.

Comment: @xdazz - it still won't work for non-IE browsers. You need to adjust the syntax so other browsers don't see the whole thing as a comment.